# Building a website using python for the first time and getting an import error, does anyone know why?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using this tutorial to build my first website and my directory setup is identical as shown in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dam0GPOAvVI

`main.py`:

```
from website import create_app
app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'kjfhksdjfh kjhdfkjsh

return app
```

After running this error is returned

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'website'
```

I have tried running the code again, changing the import/function order. When doing so, I get an error stating `create_app` is not defined.

Comment: Please check that __init__.py is in the website folder as shown in the video. Did you put __init__.py outside the website subdirectory?

Answer (score 2):

in the `website\__init__.py` file in `create_app` function first do indentation. bring `return` inside the function and  for     `app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'kjfhksdjfh kjhdfkjsh` add `'` to value to remove the syntax error

overall, in `__init__.py` change `create_app` function as below

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'kjfhksdjfh kjhdfkjsh' # <-- add ' here
    return app # <-- do indentation here
```

Comment: I had had it like this originally and the same error is present, I seem to have pasted that part of the code badly.

Comment: this code is working fine , is your `__init__.py` is in `website` folder ?

Answer (score 0):

If your main.py and init.py is in the same directory.

Try modify in `main.py` with

`from website import create_app`

to

`from init import create_app`

In addition, I found an indentation error in your init.py.

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'kjfhksdjfh kjhdfkjsh
return app
```

should be:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'kjfhksdjfh kjhdfkjsh
    return app
```

I think you may have made a typo when you wrote the question

Comment: Doing this I get an error stating "init" is not the name of a moduel, upon using pip install init, I get the same original import error.

Comment: Your original post had a formatting error which obscured the fact that you named the file `__init__.py`; it looked like it was named `init.py`

Answer (score -2):

As I see it, correct me if I'm wrong, you're trying to import your `create_app()` function from the `init.py` file.
The thing is, your import line is trying to import `create_app()` from your package (where both your files are located).

Just change the line:

`from website import create_app`

to:

`from init.py import create_app`

Comment: This would look for a file named `py` in a directory called `init`. The argument to `import` is a module, not a literal file name.

Comment: As such, the analysis is probably roughly correct. The OP has not revealed what the directory structure looks like, but `from website` is probably wrong.

Comment: Following the tutorial, that seems to be what he's trying to achieve. `from init.py` will look for that file in the current directory of the main file itself

Comment: Why do you believe that? `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'init.py'; 'init' is not a package`

Comment: Okay that's weird. I might be missing something, I'll check things again